# Add selected item from a bound listbox to a unbound listbox

Tags: c#, listbox, windows

i want to add selected item from a data bounded listbox (listbox1) to another listbox (listbox2)

Here is the code on a click event of a button.

```
private void btnrgt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string x = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
     listBox2.Items.Add(x.ToString());
     txttestno.Text = listBox2.Items.Count.ToString();
}
```

When i run this code System.data.datarowview get displayed in the listbox2.

Kindly help.
thank you in advance.

Comment: It is still showing System.data.datarowview on the second listbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you bind a `ListBox` datasource to a `DataTable` every item inside the ListBox is a `DataRowView`, not a simple string. In the ListBox you see a string displayed because you set the `DisplayMember` property of the ListBox with the name of a column in that DataRowView.

So, taking the current `SelectedItem` doesn't return a string but a DataRowView and calling `ToString()` for a DataRowView returns the full qualified name of the class (System.Data.DataRowView).

You need something like this

```
private void btnrgt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DataRowView x = listBox1.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
     if ( x != null)
     {
          listBox2.Items.Add(x["NameOfTheColumnDisplayed"].ToString());
          txttestno.Text = listBox2.Items.Count.ToString();
     }
}
```

**EDIT**
It is not clear what is the source of the error stated in your comment below, however you could try to avoid adding an item from the first listbox to the second one if that item exists in the second listbox with code like this

```
private void btnrgt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DataRowView x = listBox1.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
     if ( x != null)
     {
          string source = x"NameOfTheColumnDisplayed".ToString();
          if(!listbox2.Items.Cast<string>().Any(x => x == source))
          {
              listbox2.Items.Add(source);
              txttestno.Text = listBox2.Items.Count.ToString();
          }
     }
}
```

This solutions works if your second listbox is really populated adding simple strings to its Items collection.

Comment: Column 'Testname' is constrained to be unique.  Value 'Hameoglobin Test' is already present.      It is showing this exception if i try to add multiple items to second listbox & their are no constraints

Comment: The second listbox is binded to a DataTable?

Comment: No it is not bounded to any data table.

Comment: Uhm, however this seems to be the cause of that error message. The exception happens on the listbox2.Items.Add line?

Comment: No , exception is shown at the program.cs saying "column name is a contrained to be unique & value is already present" when i click on 2nd or following items from bounded listbox.

Comment: my main purpose is to select few items from a no of items already in the database. so i cannot bound second listbox, it had to be unbounded

Comment: Do you still have the error with the second snippet of code?

Comment: Its done , just had to unchecked the selected value option in the bound properties. Thanks alot for your help sir

Answer (score 0):

On click button use below code.

```
protected void btnGo_Click(object sender,EventArgs e) {
    string x = ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text;
    ListBox2.Items.Add(x);
}
```

Comment: string x = ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text;  .Text showing error

Comment: plz post an error. have u tried : string x = ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() ?

Comment: It is still showing System.data.datarowview on the second listbox